# Write file directly into TcpClient without storing it in memory

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, tcpclient, tcplistener

I have a 1 GB file that I need to write to a `TcpClient` object. What's the best way to do this without reading the entire file into memory?

Comment: TransmitFile() API?  As others have pointed out, the data will have to traverse memory somewhere, but the TF() API can hide this buffering in the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read it into memory at *some point* though you obviously don't need to do it all at once!

Just use `BinaryReader.Read` and read in "n" number of bytes at a time, something like:

```
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream("test.dat", FileMode.Open));
        int currentIndex = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[100];

        while (reader.Read(buffer, currentIndex, 100) > 0)
        {
            //Send buffer
            currentIndex += 100;
        }
```